# Deserializing difficultly formed XML to C# object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have XML that is returned by a 3rd party web service in the following form:

```
<object>
    <list name="subscriptions">
        <object>
            <string name="id">something</string> 
            <string name="title">something else</string> 
            <list name="categories" /> 
            <number name="timestamp">1252707770116</number> 
        </object>
        ...more 'object'...
    </list>
</object>
```

I'm having a lot of issues trying to deserialize this data to an object.  I wasn't able to generate a schema using xsd.exe, so I generated the following classes by hand to try and fit this data:

```
[XmlRoot("object")]
public class ListOfSubscriptions
{
    [XmlElement("list")]
    public Subscription[] items;
}

[XmlRoot("object")]
public class Subscription
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string id;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string title;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string[] categories;
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string timestamp;
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this with the following code:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListOfSubscriptions));
StreamReader r = new StreamReader("out.xml");
ListOfSubscriptions listSubscribe = (ListOfSubscriptions)s.Deserialize(r);
r.Close();
```

However, when it finishes, `listSubscribe` has one member and all its fields are null.

How should I be creating my template for deserializing?

Thanks

**Update - 2010/01/28**

Thanks to everybody's comments I've revised my classes to the following:

```
[XmlRoot("object")]
public class ListOfSubscriptions
{
    [XmlElement("list")]
    public SubscriptionList[] items;
}
[XmlRoot("list")]
public class SubscriptionList
{
    [XmlElement("object")]
    public Subscription[] items;
}

[XmlRoot("object")]
public class Subscription
{
    [XmlElement("string")]
    public string id;
    [XmlElement("string")]
    public string title;
    [XmlElement("list")]
    public string[] categories;
    [XmlElement("number")]
    public string timestamp;
}
```

If I comment out the [XmlElement(...)] lines in Subscription, and run, I get that `listSubscribe` has one `SubscriptionList` item which has the correct number of Subscriptions, however, all the elements of the subscriptions are null.

If I uncomment the XmlElement lines, I get an error reflecting a Subscription.  I imagine its getting confused because there are multiple elements with the same name.

How do I tie the attribute name to the class member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. However, you are only defining two classes. There are actually three classes to define:

1. The single root object, with an XML name of "object". This will have only one member:
2. The list of objects (with an XML name of "list"). This will have one member, an array of:
3. Subscriptions, with an XML name of "object".

Another problem is that you are defining the Subscription fields as attributes. They aren't attributes, they're elements.

Comment: Thanks, this has gotten me a lot closer, I'm still have issues getting data into the Subscription object, I've added details in the original post.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer, it got me the closest.  I found I can get the data in Json, so I'm using the Json.NET library to solve the deserialization problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're never going to get anywhere with XML like this:

```
<string name="id">something</string>
```

That's just created by someone who doesn't know XML. The equivalent:

```
<id>something</id>
```

would be easy to deserialize.

---

The only way I can think of for you to deserialize that is by implementing the `IXmlSerializable` interface on your class(es).

Comment: I agree, that XML would be easy to deserialize, however the XML I've been handed is from Google, you'd think they'd know better.

Comment: @Aaron: no, I think they're not considering people who want to deserialize into an object. They may expect you to process the XML directly.

Comment: I was thinking there was something not right about that XML. Glad to know it wasn't just me.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change out [XmlArry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarray.aspx) and [XMLArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarrayitems.aspx).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536947/c-serialize-second-level-element-to-property) is an example.  It should look something like this:

```
[XmlArray("FullNames")]
[XmlArrayItem("Name")]
public string[] Names{get;set;}
```

will give you

```
<FullNames>
    <Name>Michael Jackson</Name>
    <Name>Paris Hilton</Name>
</FullNames>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use XSD.exe .Net framework utility to generate a class that can be used a memory representation of your XML document.

Comment: XSD didn't come up with anything usable, I think its due to the form of XML